# Best way to display pdf document in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms, ghostscript

I'm looking for the best way to display pdf document on a website. Surely I need to convert it to jpeg or gif for the browser to handle it. I read few posts but most refer to GhostScript and its pdf2image. But that solution calls for starting a process that would save a copy of pdf doc to the file system and then would have to be loaded back into memory for displaying. Frankly I find it a bit clumsy. For those of you who have done it, what library you used and if you could attach a link to some examples, I'd greatly appreciate it. 
I'm developick a web application that helps manage manufacturing process and is accessed fron android tablets. Company has a stockpile of documentation in pdf files that is to be delivered to production managers. I'd love the solution to be akin Crystal Report Viewer contron but I I understand that I have to stick to pdf to image conversion. Please give me some advise here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By all accounts the PDF Focus .NET library seems to be the best solution. A wrd of advice is to add a cleanup method to the page unload to delete all temporary files that were used to feed source into image controls when displaying pictures on a website.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is don't over think this.

You can simply add a link to the `PDF` file, which will open on a new tab.

Comment: not a bad idea except android browsers tend to download pdf files rater than opening them in new tab.

Comment: have a look at this [project](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) it might solve that issue

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at **http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/** which will allow you to render a PDF on the client side.

Or if you decide to go with a Ghostscript, you can take a look at  **http://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com**